# Is there a way to make Firefox open a tab as a private tab?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, privacy, privacy-protection

Is there a Firefox addon that will let me open a tab as a private tab? Otherwise, I have to open a new private window.

When I open pages like Amazon I sometimes want to use them anonymized because of the cookie tracking of my searches.

Comment: Maybe a cookie-management addon would suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best alternative is to use [Private Browsing Window addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59736/). It starts a new Firefox instance with a new profile.

Answer (score 1):

I fear this is not feasible in Firefox right now. Unfortunately the same problem applies to Tor.

You could try to file a bug to request it, though.

Answer (score 0):

The **[Temporary Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/temporary-containers/)** extension adds a per-tab/container private browsing mode, isolated from other tabs/containers.

> Open tabs, websites, and links in automatically managed disposable containers. Containers isolate data websites store (cookies, storage, and more) from each other, enhancing your privacy and security while you browse.
>
> Easily open disposable containers that isolate attached data and are deleted after usage.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you addons such as **privacy badger and uBlock origin**, to block yourself from trackers.

Sites can't track with these enabled hence the anonymity.