# Is it possible to start a "Private Tab" vs a "Private Window" in Firefox 20?

Tags: firefox, browser, privacy, private-browsing

I use Firefox 20 on my Nexus 7 tablet and under Linux. This is my desktop browser string:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
```

On the tablet, it is possible to open a "Private Tab" and also Chrome supports such a feature. On my desktop, however, only the option "New Private Window" is given.

[image: Private Window]

I'd like to run Gmail in a private, pinned tab in Firefox. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make Firefox open a tab as a private tab?](https://superuser.com/questions/209228/is-there-a-way-to-make-firefox-open-a-tab-as-a-private-tab)

Answer (score 5):

Firefox extension [Private Tab](https://web.archive.org/web/20171102122057/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/private-tab/) (archived link; might not still work)
adds a per-tab private browsing mode.

It works (worked?) with Firefox 20+.

Comment: I normally try to avoid add-ons for compatibility purposes. But I made an exception here. I voted for this add-on to become default functionality.

Comment: @bartolo-otrit If I understand correctly, there is no "private" container that would e.g. clear downloads, cookies, bookmarks, history after closure, right?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, multi-account containers don't have all the features of private windows and share download history. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is not possible: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/955694